# Rails Devise user controller in subfolder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, devise, routes, subdirectory

I am using omniauth and found devise using a subfolder for this(in official example) `controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb`. I need to create a User show page as well as other actions for User so I decide to create a new UsersController inside a `controllers/users` folder. Now it looks like

```ruby
class Users::UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

`routes.rb`

```ruby
My::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
  match 'users/:id' => 'users/users#show'

  root :to => 'home#index'
end
```

it works but the route created is unnamed 
`rake routes` gives

`/users/:id(.:format)                   users/users#show`

without `GET` and `route_name`
so I'm unable to use it for example after login redirect. Is there a better way to realize the subfolder routes structure and is it good idea to group controllers like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need name your route in your route.rb

```
match 'users/:id' => 'users/users#show', :as => 'user'
```

After that you can call this route by `user_url(user.id)`

See example on guides : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes

Comment: When I do this, it looks for my view in views/users/users/show.html.erb. Why the double users folder?